# Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'"

Tags: python, poo, excepciones

Me encuentro prácticando con **Python**, haciendo un poco **POO**, una clase por aquí, otra por allá ... :) ... y, también, con manejo de ficheros y **pickle**.

Os expongo el bloque de código de un archivo llamado "gestor.py":

```
# encoding: utf-8

from io import open
import pickle


class Categoria:

    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self._id = 0
        self.nombre = nombre

    def __str__(self):
        return '\t-> [{}] - {}.'.format( self._id, self.nombre.upper() )


class Gestor_Categorias:

    categorias = []
    id_nuevo = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.cargar()

    '''
    Recogiendo el ID del último registro insertado
    '''
    def dame_id_nuevo(self):
        if len(self.categorias) == 0:
            self.id_nuevo += 1

        else:
            cat_ultimo_registro = self.categorias[-1]
            self.id_nuevo = int(cat_ultimo_registro._id) + 1

        return self.id_nuevo

    def agregar(self, cat):
        existe = self.buscar_si_existe(cat.nombre)
        if existe[0] == False:
            #Pasar el nuevo ID
            cat._id = self.dame_id_nuevo()
            self.categorias.append(cat)
            self.guardar()

    def buscar_si_existe(self, nombre):
        existe = False
        cat_bucle = ''
        for cat_bucle in self.categorias:
            if( cat_bucle.nombre == nombre ):
                existe = True
                cat_bucle = cat_bucle
        return [existe, cat_bucle]

    def mostrar(self):
        if len(self.categorias) == 0:
            print("\t-> El Gestor de CATEGORÍAS está vacío.")
            return

        print('')
        for cat in self.categorias:
            print '\t',
            print(cat)

    def cargar(self):
        fichero = open('gestor_categorias.pckl', 'ab+')
        #Como el comando anterior de APPEND pone el puntero al final,
        #habrá que recolocarlo al inicio del fichero
        fichero.seek(0)
        try:
            #en la primera carga, al estar vacío,
            #saltará hasta la excepción
            self.categorias = pickle.load(fichero)
        except:
            print("Creación satisfactoria del fichero de CATEGORÍAS ... ¡¡OK!!")
        finally:
            fichero.close()
            if( len(self.categorias) == 1 ):
                print("\nSe ha cargado {} categoría.".format( len(self.categorias) ))
            else:
                print("\nSe han cargado {} categorías.".format( len(self.categorias) ))

    def guardar(self):
        fichero = open('gestor_categorias.pckl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.categorias, fichero)
        fichero.close()

    def borrar(self, nombre):
        #Borrado total o único :: ini
        #---------------------------------------------------
        if( nombre.lower() == 'total' ):
            tot = len(self.categorias)
            for cat in self.categorias:
                self.categorias.remove( cat )
                self.guardar()

            print("""
    Se borraron todas las categorías ({} en total).
        -> El archivo quedó vacío.
            """.format( tot ))

        else:
            existe = self.buscar_si_existe(nombre)
            if existe[0]:
                self.categorias.remove( existe[1] )
                self.guardar()

                print( '\nLa categoría llamada "{}" fue borrada.'.format( nombre ) )
                #return
        #---------------------------------------------------
        #Borrado total o único :: fin

    # Destructor de clase
    def __del__(self):
        self.guardar()  # guardado automático
        print("\n:: Se ha guardado el fichero de CATEGORÍAS - FIN ::")



#Acciones de Ejecución
#==========================================================
#[ CATEGORÍAS ]
''''''
gC = Gestor_Categorias()
gC.mostrar()
gC.agregar( Categoria('Arqueros') )
```

Al ejecutar este código, tras crearse el archivo si aún no existe, se lanza la siguiente excepción referida, creo, al método "**__del__**" de la clase "*Gestor_Categorias*":

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'" in <bound method Gestor_Categorias.__del__ of <__main__.Gestor_Categorias instance at 0x7f82dc406f38>> ignored
```

En el método "**__del__**" de la clase "*Gestor_Categorias*", llamo al método de "guardar()" para hacer un guardado de los cambios del archivo al cerrar el programa.

Como curiosidad, tengo otro archivo calcado a éste con otras dos clases (Personaje y Gestor_Personajes) que también guarda los registros de la misma manera en un archivo y al cerrar (con su "__del__") llama a su "guardar()" pero no se lanza esta excepción.

He visto algún otro post sobre excepciones parecidas pero no llego a solucionarlo con las recomendaciones que he leido.

Entonces, ¿alguien me puede ayudar a entender por qué se lanza la excepción?, ¿cómo resolverla?, ¿es necesario no implementar el método __del__? y, si no se puede implementar, ¿dónde podría hacer la última llamada a "guardar()" que tengo en __del__ antes de cerrar?

Gracias por las posibles respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error nos da una pista:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'

O sea que `pickle`ahora es `None` y por tanto no tiene el atributo/método `dump`.

Otra pista, **si llamas a `__del__` explícitamente al final del código todo funciona** como esperamos. ¿Qué está pasando aquí?

Pues que simple y llanamente se produce la llamada a `__del__` durante el proceso de terminación del intérprete (dado que tu programa ha terminado cuando tu objeto queda sin referencias y el GC se hace cargo) y en este punto las variables globales, incluidos los imports puede haber pasado a mejor vida antes que la propia instancia del objeto. Nuestra importación de `pickle` no existe en el momento en el que se produce la llamada a `__del__` por parte del GC. La propia documentación del método nos avisa:

> `__del__()` can be executed during interpreter shutdown. As a consequence, the global variables it needs to access (including other modules) may already have been deleted or set to None. Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__(`) method is called.

Lo que viene a decir:

> `__del __ ()` se puede ejecutar durante el apagado del intérprete. Como consecuencia, las variables globales a las que necesita acceder (incluidos otros módulos) pueden haberse eliminado o establecidas a `None`. Python garantiza que las variables globales cuyo nombre comience con un único guión bajo se eliminen de su módulo antes de que se eliminen otras variables globales; si no existen otras referencias a tales variables globales, esto puede ayudar a asegurar que los módulos importados todavía estén disponibles en el momento en que se llame al método `__del__ ()`.

Dado que **no tenemos garantías de que los imports estén vivos en este punto** porque no tenemos en nuestra mano saber el momento exacto en el que el GC va a destruir el objeto, el uso de `__del__` es extremadamente frágil en este caso. En general hay que tener mucho cuidado con `__del__` ya que es susceptible a problema que afecten al funcionamiento del GC, por ejemplo a referencias circulares.

En casos como este, una aproximación mucho más robusta es implementar nuestro propio [`context manager`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) en vez de recurrir a `__del__`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, ext_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.guardar()
    print("\n:: Se ha guardado el fichero de CATEGORÍAS - FIN ::")
```

Después instanciamos usando `with`:

```
with Gestor_Categorias() as gC:
    gC.mostrar()
    gC.agregar( Categoria('Arqueros') )
```

> **NOTA:** El método `__del__` siempre será llamado cuando el objeto sea destruido a causa de que su contador de referencias llega a 0 y el intérprete sigue en funcionamiento. Sin embargo, no podemos dar por hecho que siempre se va a llamar al método `__del__` en el caso en el que un objeto existe cuando el intérprete termina. Esto es especialmente cierto para Python 2.7 cuando hay referencias circulares que evitan que el GC destruya el objeto, viviendo este hasta que el interprete termina. En Python >= 3.4 ([PEP-442](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/)) esto último está solventado.

---

Esto no tiene que ver con la pregunta, es solo una observación. Para eliminar todos los elementos de una lista hacer:

```
for cat in self.categorias:
    self.categorias.remove( cat )
```

Es ineficiente además que por norma general **nunca debes modificar la longitud de un iterable** mientra iteras sobre el vía `for in` o usando un iterador. Para limpiar una lista usa:

```
del self.categorias[:]
```

O en Python 3 también:

```
self.categorias.clear()
```

Comment: Gracias [FJ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) por tu respuesta a la cuestión planteada sobre la excepción y gracias, también, por tu observación extra para mejorar el código; tenida en cuenta igualmente. Saludos. **NOTA**: hago el comentario a través de mi cuenta registrada [zacktagnan] ya que esta pregunta la hice desde [PJCM], una cuenta de invitado (finalmente, completé el registro pero hubo un cruce de IDs de usuario y se creó otra cuenta).
A la espera de que se haga efectiva mi demanda de combinar perfiles. :)